# When is an image formed?

Tags: visible-light

> Every part of the  page is illuminated with reflected light from your forehead, your nose, your chin, and every other part of your face. You don't see an image of your face on the page because there is too much overlapping of light. But put a barrier with a pinhole.....

The "overlapping of light" part seems very vague to me. Could somebody shed some more light on it?(Pun not intended)

**Note:** This is an extract from Hewitt's *Conceptual Physics*.

Comment: This may help as it shows that you need to have a very narrow pencil of rays to form a sharpish image.  http://pinhole.stanford.edu/howitworks/size.htm

Comment: You might be interested in the definition I use in introductory class. [I wrote it in an answer on another question on the site.](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/192469/520)